# Run Pixelmator ML Super Resolution on multiple images from terminal?

Tags: terminal, resolution, image-editing, pixelmator

Have about 1000 images with the size of 480x320px, and they are very poor quality. I tried the Pixelmator ML Super Resolution to increase the quality (1440x960) and it seems to perform well! So I thought to iterate the 1000 files, from terminal, and change the format from jpg to HEIC.

When I tried this, the HEIC file is 142K and the originl jpg is 400K. So a win win??

But how can I iterate the files, use ML Super Resolution, and save the file to a new HEIC format?

Comment: https://www.pixelmator.com/tutorials/batch-process-images-using-the-automator-app-and-pixelmator-pro/

Comment: This is the way. Went from 800 low res images, 200mb to 800 pretty high res images, 75 mb webp.